# Find length of specific dimension of 2D list

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array, count, 2d

I need to check the length of the first dimension of a 2 dimensional list of integers 'centreX1' before following loop:

```
  for (x = 0; x < (int)centreX1[0].Count(); x++)
            {
                if (BinarySpotsInsideTolerance1[0][x] == 1)
                {
                    AllspotsY.Add(centreY1[0][x]);
                    AllspotsX.Add(centreX1[0][x]);
                    AllspotsRLU.Add(RLUSpotsthreshold1[0][x]);
                }
            }
```

An error is thrown at centreX1[0].Count() if centreX1 has no members.

Comment: Check that `centreX1.Count > 0` before running the code.

Comment: if it is array then your answer is in your question title

Comment: Not an array - a list of lists of integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't count the number of elements in `centreX1[0]`, if `centreX1` has no elements.

Make sure `centreX1` has elements in it, before trying to access the first one.

```
if (centreX1.Any())  // or "if (centreX1.Count() > 0)"
{
    for (x = 0; x < (int)centreX1[0].Count(); x++)
    {
        if (BinarySpotsInsideTolerance1[0][x] == 1)
        {
            AllspotsY.Add(centreY1[0][x]);
            AllspotsX.Add(centreX1[0][x]);
            AllspotsRLU.Add(RLUSpotsthreshold1[0][x]);
        }
    }
}
```